# Why cant i use a character as a condition in a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char sum[100],x[100];


while(x != '=' )
{
cout << "\n Enter number : ";
cin >> x;
sum=sum+x;
}   
cout << sum;
return 0;
}
```

having trouble creating a program where users can input as many numbers to sum up and will only end when they input '='.i cant seem to get this to work when i input the character '=' as the error, invalid operands of types 'char [100]' and 'char [100]' to binary 'operator+', pops up

Comment: `x` is not a char, but a char **array**.

Comment: Use `std::string x;` and `while(x != "=")` instead. `sum=sum+x;` will fail in both cases though.

Comment: `sum=sum+x;` is also suspicious...

Comment: Not only is `x` not a char, but not initialized, either.

Comment: You seem to have skipped some of the early and basic chapters in your beginners text-book or tutorial. What is `x`? What is `sum`? What is `sum = sum + x` supposed to do?

Comment: Also, always build with extra warning enabled, and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: In C++ you really should learn to use std::vector for this (instead of allocating 100 items using a "C" style array and hope it will be enough)> . Then if you use std::vector you can just use std::accumulate to get the sum of the whole array in a readable line of code. Also `sum` should not be an array at all.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix warnings.  ???  Profit.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This problem was **not** caused by typos and it's clearly reproducible. It even has comments and answers that address the problem! Sure, it's a fundamental misunderstanding, but that doesn't make it a typo.

Comment: Close voters: don't forget, you were a beginner once, too.

Comment: Here's what your program could look like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/I2kJRLrUhsmwgYfT

Answer (score -1):

You may be mistaken with the type the variable `x` is. `x` is defined as a char array with the line `char x[100]` so in order to see the values inside you need to specify an index such as `x[49]` to get the 50th element which in your case would be the char value you wish to compare to "=".

A for loop may be useful as well to figuring out your problem.

Answer (score -1):

As the comment said, x is not a char but an array of char 
I suggest using `strcmp` function, if the value returned is different than 0 then they are different 
Syntax :
`int strcmp(const char* firstString, const char* secondString)`

`if(strcmp(x,"=")!= 0)`

Comment: Note that `strcmp` is a C library function. In C++, it is better to use what the C++ library provides, such as `std::string` here.

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to check whether the user typed the single character `'='`, all you need to do is look for it:

```
while (x[0] != '=')
    // body of the loop
```

That works because `x` is an **array** of `char`; when you read into an array of `char` the characters are inserted into the array in the order in which they are encountered. So if the user types just plain `'='` that will be the first character in the array, i.e., `x[0]`.

Note, however, that the array `x` has not been initialized, so the first time through the loop, the value of `x[0]` is indeterminate. That also has a simple fix:

```
char x[100] = "";
```

There's no reason to go to more complex solutions like `strcmp` or `std::string` for this part of the code.

Comment: Though `cin >> x;` may not be the best idea prior to C++20 since there was an `operator>>` overload taking `char*` instead of `char(&)[N]`. Writing out of bounds was a real problem, just like with `gets`. A `std::string` would be safer.

Comment: This is solving the wrong problem. OP is obviously trying to input and sum numbers...

Comment: @rustyx -- this is answering the question that was asked. That's part of solving the overall problem. If you want to say more, you could certainly write your own answer if the question hadn't been prematurely closed. Vote to reopen it.